# ReactJS: Update values without reload the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this problem, when I do a insert or a change about some data, to see the new data I need to reload the page while I would to update automatically the value without the need to reload the page. How can I do?

This is the part where the user click on submit and the post

```
_onSubmit(Document)
    {
        const self = this
        if ( !_.isEmpty(Document) )
        {
            //..
            if (Document && !_.isEmpty(Document.Anagraphics))
            {
                alertify.confirm(
                    utility.t('sureYouWanna_SAVE'),
                    () => {
                        const now = new Date();
                        Document._id = `PRODUCT:${new Date().getTime()}-${utility.CUID()}`
                        Document.CreationDate = now.toISOString()
                        Document.CategoryCode 
                        Document.Status = 'New';
                        Document.Type = 'PRODUCT';
                        self._POST(Document)
                    },
                    function(){}
                ).set('labels', {ok: utility.t('YES_SAVE'), cancel: utility.t('CANCEL')})
            }
            else
            {
                $methods.WarnMissingValues()
            }
        }
        else {
            $methods.WarnMissingValues()
        }
    }



_POST(Document)
    {
        console.log("DOCUMENT POST", Document)
        const self = this
        const auth = this.props.db.auth
        fetch(`${this.props.db.couch_db_host_url}requests`,{
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(`${auth.username}:${auth.password}`)
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(Document)
        })
        .then(response => {
            alertify.dismissAll()
            if(response.status > 299 || response.status < 200){
                alertify.error(utility.t('AN_ERROR_OCCURRED'))
                self._updateState({ submitSucceeded: false })
            }
            else{
                alertify.alert(utility.t('ITEM_EDITED_OK'), function(){})
                self.props.history.push({
                    pathname: RoutesIT.products_details
                })
            }
        })
        .catch((err, warning) => {
            if (err)
            {
                alertify.dismissAll()
                alertify.error(utility.t('AN_ERROR_OCCURRED'))
                console.log('_POST', err);
                self._updateState({ submitSucceeded: false })
            }
            else
            {
                console.log(warning)
                alertify.dismissAll()
                alertify.warning(utility.t(warning))
            }
        })
    }
```

How can I do to not reload the page to see the result of the post? Thank you

UPDATE:

In the page I have also:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { app: { login, p, c, l, c_timestamp, p_timestamp, l_timestamp }, form } = state;
    return {
        db: login ? login.db : null,
        Sender: login ? login.Location : null,
        timestamp: login ? login.timestamp : null,
        [ FORM_NAME ]: form[FORM_NAME],
        products: p,
        locations: l,
        categories: c, 
        categories_timestamp: c_timestamp,
        products_timestamp: p_timestamp,
        locations_timestamp: l_timestamp,
        utente: login,
    };
}
```

while the reducers

```
case actions.CATE_UPDATE:
    {
      return {
        ...state,
        c: action.payload,
        c_timestamp: new Date().getTime()
      }
    }
```

Comment: You need to add the data to the state too, after you post the item to the api, from your example code, that is not clear how you store your existing data, I could not provide a working example.

Comment: If you use post method of HTML form then browser will force reload, you must return false in onSubmit event. I think you should use ajax to send your data to server, the page won't reload and you can't receiver response on callback ajax.

Comment: I use redux to save the state could be this the problem?

Comment: I don't understand how to do.. Which part I should see in your opinion?

Comment: You said you use Redux, right? Would you mind posting the code for your reducer, the part where you are updating the data? Reducers are often the root of errors like this, so it's a good place to start looking for the issue.

Comment: @LonelyPrincess I have done an update :)

Comment: Thanks! At first glance I cannot see anything wrong with your reducer. Can you confirm if your reducer is being called when you submit the data? Where are you dispatching the `CATE_UPDATE` action in the code above? It should be somewhere in your `_POST` method, but I cannot tell which is the name of the method that dispatches it. Do you have a prop in `mapDispatchToProps` to dispatch `CATE_UPDATE`?

Comment: maybe it is the problem, I don't have a mapDispatchToProps. I don't think as you can see that the reducer is called when I submit data

Comment: Yeah, if you don't have a `mapDispatchToProps`, then the reducer is not even being run. That would explain why it doesn't work, your state is not changing. You need to use `mapDispathToProps` to be able to dispatch your `CATE_UPDATE` action from your `_POST` method. :)

Comment: mmh I'm not very expert about redux.. So i need only to create a mapDispatchToProps?

Answer (score 1):

For what I can see in your code, the problem may lie in the fact that you're not dispatching any action when you submit the data.

Redux store can only be modified via actions, and since you're not triggering any, its contents are never being updated. This explains why your component is not updated in real time: your local data is never changing, so React is not aware of any updates. Things works when you reload the page because you're probably fetching the data from server, where the data did change during your `POST` request.

In order to fix this issue, you first need to pass a `mapDispatchToProp` to the your component, same as what you did with `mapStateToProps`:

```
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(YourComponent);
```

Inside of `mapDispatchToProps`, you have to return a property containing a function that will dispatch the `CATE_UPDATE` action you want to run:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  cateUpdateAction: (payload) => dispatch({
    type: CATE_UPDATE,
    payload
  }),
});
```

Once you've done that, you'll be able to access this function from your component's props and call it inside of your `_POST` method.

```
if (response.status > 299 || response.status < 200){
  alertify.error(utility.t('AN_ERROR_OCCURRED'))
   self._updateState({ submitSucceeded: false })
} else {
  alertify.alert(utility.t('ITEM_EDITED_OK'), function(){})

  // Dispatch action to update data in Redux store
  self.props.cateUpdateAction(data_to_save);

  self.props.history.push({
    pathname: RoutesIT.products_details
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so I need to understand what insert in the "data_to_save"?

Comment: Because If i pass the document, when I click on save I receive this error: 
_POST ReferenceError: CATE_UPDATE is not defined

Comment: You should replace `data_to_save` with what you wanted to save in the store, what you expected the `action.payload` in your reducer to be. I don't really know what it is, that's logic inner to your application. :) As for that error, you probably haven't imported the `CATE_UPDATE` constant in the file where you defined `mapDispatchToProps`.